# Comparison between Lebesgue and Peano-Jordan measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Notation:**

Let $\mathcal{PJ}$ be the algebra of Peano-Jordan measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ and let $\mathcal{A(PJ)}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by it.

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{B}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ For every $E \in \mathcal{L},$ let $|E|$ be the Lebesgue measure of $E$.

Finally, let $\mathcal{I}$ be the family of closed and bounded intervals in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Note that $\mathcal{A(I)}=\mathcal{B}.$

We have:

$$\mathcal{PJ} \subseteq \mathcal{L} \Rightarrow \mathcal{A(PJ)} \subseteq \mathcal{L}.$$

I would like to know if $\mathcal{A(PJ)} \subsetneq \mathcal{L}$ or $\mathcal{A(PJ)} = \mathcal{L}.$

By completeness, every Lebesgue set is union of a Borel set and a Lebesgue set of measure zero.

Moreover,
$$\mathcal{I}\subseteq \mathcal{PJ} \Rightarrow \mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A(PJ)}.$$

So $\mathcal{A(PJ)} = \mathcal{L}$ iff every $$E\in \mathcal{L}, |E|=0 \Rightarrow E \in \mathcal{A(PJ)}.$$

I have no idea whether there is a proper inclusion or an equality in $\mathcal{A(PJ)} \subseteq \mathcal{L},$ so any comment will be useful.

Thanks in advance to everybody.